# Lazy evaluation and promise data structure

Tags: r, promise, lazy-evaluation

I have been grappling with the application of promise since I first read about it on Advanced R. It is mentioned that a promise is a data structure that powers lazy evaluation. The concept of lazy evaluation is quite clear as function arguments are only evaluated whenever they are accessed. However, in some examples I just cannot discover the presence of a promise and how/where it is evaluated. Consider the following example from Advanced R:

```
y <- 10
h02 <- function(x) {
  y <- 100
  x + 1
}

h02(y)
[1] 11
```

It returns 11 instead of 101, as apparently when we assign a variable like `y` which already exists in the global environment to `x` it is bound and evaluated outside of the function.
So I would like to know is a promise always involved some sort of assignment or every expression could be a promise and how we can detect their presence.
It is mentioned that they are evaluated in the calling environment of a function. So the second question is are their evaluation environments different from normal arguments as user-defined arguments are evaluated outside of the function.

There is also another example which I cannot understand why it involves lazy evaluation, and we only see `Calculating...` once.

```
double <- function(x) {
message("Calculating...")
x * 2
}
h03 <- function(x) {
c(x, x)
}
h03(double(20))
Calculating...
[1] 40 40
```

I am so sorry if I sound a little bit confused here, I got the point but it has never quite sunk in and I wanted to ask for a little bit of explanation for which I am very grateful.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking here. Promises do know what environment they are created in and are evaluated there. There is no base R way to check if something is a promise because as soon as you look at it, it is evaluated and is no longer a promise. A promise will never be evaluated more than once. Promises are more of an implementation detail rather than something you work with directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand, it is just that sometimes I fail to have an explanation for them and how they occur for example I would like to know why my second example is a promise and therefore evaluated only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object such as `y` within h02 is created in a function it is created in the local execution frame/environment of that function (a new frame is created each time the function is run).  The created object is distinct from an object of the same name in any other environment.

Regarding h03 once a promise is forced, i.e. evaluated, its value is stored in the promise's `value` component and its `evaled` component is set to TRUE so that upon further accesses it does not have to be evaluated again.

Arguments of functions are promises but normally not other objects.  Use pryr to inspect objects.

```
library(pryr)

f <- function(x) { 
  z <- 1

  cat("is_promise(z):", is_promise(z), "\n")

  cat("is_promise(x):", is_promise(x), "\n")
  cat("before forcing - promise_info(x):\n")
  print(promise_info(x))

  force(x)
  cat("after forcing - promise_info(x):\n")
  print(promise_info(x))

  delayedAssign("w", 3)
  cat("is_promise(w):", is_promise(w), "\n")

  invisible()
}
a <- 3
f(a)
```

giving:

```
is_promise(z): FALSE 
is_promise(x): TRUE 
before forcing - promise_info(x):
$code
a

$env
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

$evaled
[1] FALSE

$value
NULL

after forcing - promise_info(x):
$code
a

$env
NULL

$evaled
[1] TRUE

$value
[1] 3

is_promise(w): TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanations. I really appreciate your time. I just have two very simple questions. In the case of `h02(y)` is it safe to say that as a general rule, since `y` is a user-defined argument it is evaluated in the calling environment of the function which in this case is the global environment, so that's why even if we have one `y` in the execution frame the function use the one in the calling environment for the computation?

Comment: Yes, if you are saying that the promises created from arguments are always evaluated in the caller's environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Mr. Grothendieck. I was hoping you would consider my question and I am very grateful now.